# Двойной onCreateView и onResume в PlaceholderFragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragment

Приветствую.

Я использую стандартную комплектацию `TabbedActivity` в `AndroidStudio`, у которой в классе `MainActivity` реализованы сам класс `MainActivity`, фрагмент `PlaceholderFragment` и его `Adapter`, я прописал логи и при запуске программы в логах вызывается метод `onCreate` главного `Activity` и дважды `onCreateView`  `Fragment`, я не могу понять, почему метод `onCreateView` вызывается дважды? У меня реализован `MediaPlayer` во `Fragment`, и если я пролистаю раз, то он не переходит в состояние `stop` с первого раза, хотя в методе `onStop`, и `onDestroyView` я устанавливаю `MediaPlayer.stop`. Нужно пролистать дважды, только тогда срабатывает метод `onStop`, почему так? Как мне отловить второе `onCreateView`? Я так полагаю один `Fragment`  я вижу непосредственно, а другой живет в памяти? Если да, то как к нему получить доступ, и задать нужные мне параметры и в его методах `onStop` и `onDestroyView`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вам следует подробнее почитать про `PagerAdapter` и `FragmentPagerAdapter`.

> логах вызывается метод `onCreate` главного `Activity` и дважды `onCreateView`  `Fragment`

- Это происходит для того, чтоб обеспечить плавный переход на следующую страницу! Ведь если вы плавно поведёте пальцем в сторону следующей страницы - вы уже видите готовый фрагмент.

> Я так полагаю один `Fragment` я вижу непосредственно, а другой живет в памяти

- Когда Вы переходите на второй фрагмент, в памяти уже живёт 3 фрагмента ;) тот что, слева и тот, что справа.

Для решения Вашей задачи - Вам скорее всего следует подписаться на событие `OnTabSelectedListener`, и через адаптер отдавать команды на остановку или запуск MediaPlayer.